# How to implement an interface and inherit from another specialized template at the same time

Tags: c++, inheritance, pure-virtual

Let's say we have following interfaces

```
// interface

template <typename T>
class MyInterface
{
public:
    virtual void fun1() = 0;
    virtual void fun2() = 0;
}

// just specialization, keep pure virtual
class SpecInterface: public MyInterface<int>
{
}
```

Then in implementation

```
// interface_impl

template <typename T>
class MyServiceImpl : public MyInterface<T>
{
    virtual void fun1() override {
        std::cout << "concrete MyService f1" << std::endl;
    }
    
    // keep fun2 unimplemented
}

class SpecInterfaceImpl : public SpecInterface
{
    // I want the MyServiceImpl::fun1 here

    virtual void fun2() override {
        std::cout << "concrete SpecService f2" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Now I want to implement the `SpecInterface` and also inherit from `MyServiceImpl::fun1`. How to do that?
In UML:
[image]

I tried multiple inheritance but without luck.

Comment: Please explain what you mean here: "also inherit from `MyServiceImpl::fun1`"

Comment: I mean inherit the implementation details of `MyServiceImpl<int>::fun1()`, and only implement `fun2()` to make the class can be initialized.

Comment: Mixing static and dynamic polymorphism, are you really sure you need it? Specifically MyInterface has no dependency on T at all. In general my advice if you have an "interface" depending on `T` stick with static polymorphism the whole way. And to reuse code use CRTP (mixin) to pull in implementations for the static polymorphic interface.

Comment: Hint: if you rotate your picture 45 degrees, you get a diamond.

Comment: the diagram kinda reminds  Cheshire Cat\PIMPL

Answer (score 1):

Do you perhaps mean something like this?

```
#include <iostream>

// interfaces
class interface1_t
{
public:
    virtual ~interface1_t() = default;
    virtual void method1() = 0;
};

class interface2_t
{
public:
    virtual ~interface2_t() = default;
    virtual void method2() = 0;
};

// mixin classes for interface implementations
template <typename base_t>
class interface1_impl : public interface1_t
{
public:
    void method1() override
    {
        std::cout << "method1\n";
    }
};

template <typename base_t>
class interface2_impl : public interface2_t
{
public:
    void method2() override
    {
        std::cout << "method2\n";
    }
};

// this class will implement both interfaces
// by mixin in both implementations.
// this pattern will never lead to diamond inheritance
class my_class_t :
    public interface1_impl<my_class_t>,
    public interface2_impl<my_class_t>
{
};


int main()
{
    my_class_t my_class;
    my_class.method1();
    my_class.method2();
}
```